# Duplicate interface definition for class MainScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this line in my MainScene.h file.

```
 @interface MainScene : CCNode <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>
```

I redeclared it adding this line:

```
 @interface MainScene : CCScene
```

I'm trying to add a collision on my objective-c/cocos2d iOS app as well as a main menu scene that will transition to the game scene.  I am following one tutorial for the collision effect (https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/369/build-your-own-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and) and this tutorial for the main menu scene (http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2014/02/how-to-make-flappy-bird-like-game-using-cocos2d/).  The code (uploaded on github) for the main menu scene uses CCScene and the code for the collision effect as well as the entire game scene uses CCNode.

So my question is....how do I make it work?  How do I combine CCNode and CCScene together?

I want to add the following code to my MainScene.h:

```
 @interface IntroScene : CCScene


 + (IntroScene *)scene;
 - (id)init;


 @end
```

replace IntroScene with MainScene

but if I do that, I get Warnings in my MainScene.m file:

You guys might ask me what the Warnings are but I'll post that up later.

This is the error I get which is making me wonder how I can get CCNode and CCScene to work together, if at all:

in IntroScene.m

```
 - (void)onPlayClicked:(id)sender
 {
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainScene scene]
                           withTransition:[CCTransition transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:1.0f]];
 }
```

ARC Semantic error: No known class method for selector 'scene'
Semantic issue: Incompatible pointer types sending 'MainScene*' to parameter of type 'CCScene *'

**UPDATE....My current code as of now:**

IntroScene.h (error: Expected ';' after method prototype)

```
 #import "cocos2d.h"
 #import "cocos2d-ui.h"

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 /**
  *  The intro scene
  *  Note, that scenes should now be based on CCScene, and not CCLayer, as previous versions
  *  Main usage for CCLayer now, is to make colored backgrounds (rectangles)
  *
  */
 @interface IntroScene : CCScene

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 //+ (IntroScene *)scene;
 //- (id)init;

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 + (id)scene
 {
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

IntroScene *layer = [IntroScene node];

[scene addChild: layer];

return scene;
 }

 -(id) init
 {

if( (self=[super init] )) {

}
return self;
 }

 - (void) dealloc
 {

 [super dealloc];
 }

 @end
```

IntroScene.m (Error: No known class method for selector 'scene') <-- bottom of the code in the replaceScene line

```
 // Import the interfaces
 #import "IntroScene.h"
 #import "MainScene.h"

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 #pragma mark - IntroScene
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 @implementation IntroScene

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 #pragma mark - Create & Destroy
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 + (IntroScene *)scene
 { 
return [[self alloc] init];
 }

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 - (id)init
 {
// Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
self = [super init];
if (!self) return(nil);

CCSprite *fxBackground = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"MarioBackground-static.png"];
fxBackground.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
fxBackground.position    = ccp(0, 0);
[self addChild:fxBackground];

CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"SUPER TORTOISE BROS."
                                       fontName:@""
                                       fontSize:40.0f];
label.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
label.color = [CCColor whiteColor];
label.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.6f);
[self addChild:label];

CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"buttonPlay.png"];
CCButton *playButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:frame];
playButton.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
playButton.position = ccp(30, 120);
[playButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onSpinningClicked:)];
[self addChild:playButton];

frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"buttonScore.png"];
CCButton *scoreButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:frame];
scoreButton.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
scoreButton.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width - 130, 120);
//  [scoreButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(todo:)];
[self addChild:scoreButton];


// done
return self;
 }

 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 #pragma mark - Button Callbacks
 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

 - (void)onPlayClicked:(id)sender
 {
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainScene scene]
                           withTransition:[CCTransition  transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:1.0f]];
 }


 // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 @end
```

MainScene.h

```
 @interface MainScene : CCScene <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>
 {
 }

 +(MainScene*) scene;


 @end
```

Code snippet from MainScene.m:

```
 @implementation MainScene {
CCButton *_restartButton;
CCSprite *_hero;
CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
CCNode *_ground1;
CCNode *_ground2;
NSArray *_grounds;
NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;
NSMutableArray *_obstacles;
BOOL _gameOver;
BOOL Start;
CGFloat _scrollSpeed;
NSInteger _points;
CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
CCLabelTTF *_highScore;
 }
```

Do I declare my MainMenu scene class in between the brackets in the above snippet?  If so how?

Not sure how I would put this (below) into my implementation...

```
 +(MainMenu) scene
  {
 CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
 return scene;
 }
```

Comment: Is your MainScene.h being imported into IntroScene.m?  The error seems to indicate that it doesn't know about `@interface MainScene : CCScene`.  Also, does MainScene have a '+ (MainScene *)scene' method?

Comment: @PhillipMills - yes, IntroScene.m has MainScene.h imported.  This is the code in MainScene.h:

`@interface MainScene : CCNode <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>
//@end
//@interface MainScene : CCScene

+ (MainScene *)scene;
//- (id)init;

@end`

I get the following warnings:


IntroScene.m


`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainScene scene]`

Incompatible pointer types sending 'MainScene *' to parameter of type 'CCScene *'


MainScene.m


`@implementation MainScene  {`

Method definition for 'scene' not found

Comment: OK, so the "incompatible pointer" problem is because MainScene is not a CCScene subclass.  The other warning seems to be because you don't have a `+ (MainScene *)scene {…}` in your implementation.  You need to decide what kind of thing `MainScene` is going to be and then only use it in methods that match its definition.

Comment: @PhillipMills - yea that's the problem.  MainScene is going to be where the game scene will be.  It is the scene that the IntroScene transitions to when the app first launches.  However, the tutorials I used call for two different classes, CCNode (for object collision) and  CCScene (for scene transitioning).  So I'm trying to figure out how to make them work together.  My current MainScene code won't work without CCNode class and the scene transition won't work without the CCScene class.

Answer (score 1):

CCScene inherits from CCNode. Use the following for interface declaration

```
@interface MainScene : CCScene <CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>
+ (MainScene *)scene;
@end
```

Also, make sure you've implemented your `+ (MainScene *)scene` method. Enable user interaction in the class either in init or onEnter as per your requirement and this should allow you to take advantage of object collision as well scene transitioning.

**EDIT**

You are getting the ";" error because you are trying to define a function in the header file in IntroScene.h. You should only declare your functions in the header file i.e. if you want them to be public. Your IntroScene.h should look like this.

```
@interface IntroScene : CCScene

+(IntroScene*) scene;
-(id) init;
@end
```

There are various other flaws in your code. I'd suggest going through a tutorial to brush up certain concepts. [Raywenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial) would be a good place to start.

Comment: thanks, but now I get errors when I try and implement the method:

`+ (id)scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    
    IntroScene *layer = [IntroScene node];
    
    [scene addChild: layer];
    
    return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
    
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    
    [super dealloc];
}
`

I get an error saying Expected ';' after method prototype.

If I put a semicolon after the method prototype, I get Expected identifier or '(' warning for the open brackets.

Comment: could you please update your answer with the latest code? It'll help understand your code better..

Comment: I get the following error: No known class method for selector 'scene'

for this code in IntroScene.m:

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainScene scene]`

No Warnings are showing up.

Comment: You are calling a static function from MainScene class called "scene" which is not declared in the header file. You need to declare  +(MainScene*) scene;in the header and also implement the function in the implementation file.

Comment: A bit confused....

I have MainScene declared in my MainScene.h file.  No errors showed up, but now a warning showed up referring to this code:

`@implementation MainScene {
    CCButton *_restartButton;
    CCSprite *_hero;
    CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
    CCNode *_ground1;
    CCNode *_ground2;
    NSArray *_grounds;
    NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;
    NSMutableArray *_obstacles;
    BOOL _gameOver;
    BOOL Start;
    CGFloat _scrollSpeed;
    NSInteger _points;
    CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
    CCLabelTTF *_highScore;
}`

Method definition for 'scene' not found.

Comment: you need to define your scene method in the implementation file.

Comment: updated code posted for MainScene.h with a snippet from MainScene.m.  Not really sure how to fully implement my class that I declared.  IntroScene.m and IntroScene.h has no problems, but MainScene.m uses brackets in its implementation and has a bunch of other code unlike IntroScene.m.